# Основы JS Как вернуть функцию в случае не выполнения условия?

Tags: javascript

Я пытался найти ответ но не нашел. В общем у меня есть массив и в нём 4 элемента. 
Генерирую случайное число 0-10. Если оно совпадает с индексом в массиве, мы выводим слово из массива, естесственно 0, 1, 2, 3 мне выведет слово. Но если такого индекса в массиве нету, нужно чтобы ничего не выводило но запустило функцию заново и сразу вывело совпадение. Просто при обновлении страницы всегда должно выходить алерт с сообщением от 0-3 из массива. Что нужно прописать в else? Заранее спасибо! Если корявый код извините, совсем новичок в этом.

```
let masItems = [
    "cat",
    "horse",
    "apple",
    "orange"
];

let randomNum = Math.random() * 10;
randomNum = randomNum.toFixed(0);
console.log(randomNum);

function randomMas() {
    if (randomNum <= masItems.length) {
        alert(`Случайное слово из массива: ${masItems[randomNum]}`);

    } else {
        return;
    }
}

randomMas();
```

Comment: Эмм... А почему нельзя сделать `let randomNum = Math.random() * masItems.length;` чтобы ничего повторно не вызывать?) Ну ответом на ваш вопрос будет `else { randomMas(); }` — функция будет вызывать саму себя.

Comment: Math.random() * masItems.length я не знал об этом и даже не задумался. Теперь это очень полезное применение для меня. Используя ответы + книга  я переделал код в одно строчку и всё работает так же как я задумал. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let masItems = [
  "cat",
  "horse",
  "apple",
  "orange"
];

function randomMas(index) {
  console.log(index);

  if (index < masItems.length) {
    console.log(`Случайное слово из массива: ${masItems[index]}`);
  } else {
    randomMas(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }
}

randomMas(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Да, я тоже только что изменил <= на <

Comment: @Raymond Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Answer (score 1):

Изучив ещё немного информации по книге, я смог сделать вывод случайного массива всего лишь одной строчкой. Может новичкам понадобится, добавлю запись сюда.

```
let masItems = [
  "cat",
  "horse",
  "apple",
  "orange"
];

console.log("Случайное слово из массива: " + masItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * masItems.length)]);
```

или для того чтобы консоль так же показывала это самое случайное число + выводила массив точно так же как в ответе ранее через функцию:

```
 let masItems = [
  "cat",
  "horse",
  "apple",
  "orange"
];

let indexNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * masItems.length);
console.log(indexNum);
console.log("Случайное слово из массива: " + masItems[indexNum]);
```